# Why table header is also sorting with table data in jade?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

> Here is my code sample that is working perfect but the only problem is that when i click on table header its sort the data but also it include the table header itself.(Table header also sorted)

```
.Container.feedPageComponent.feedPageHome
 script(src='/dashboard/bootstrap/js/tablesort.js')
 script.
  var something = function(text) {
    console.log('something', text);
    var value = text;
    window.location.href="#{baseUrl}/feed/searchData/"+value
  }
  function init() {
   new Tablesort(document.getElementById('myTable'));
    }
  window.onload = init;
 div.input
            input(type="text",id="demo" name="title", placeholder="Search Your Articles",onchange="something(this.value)")
  div
    table#myTable.table.table-striped
      tr
         th Date
         th Time
         th Title
         th Type
         th Delete
         th User
         th Share
      - for item in data.rows.feedArray
        tr
          - var a = new Date(item.publishDate)
          if a == "Invalid Date"
            td N/A
            td
          else
            td #{a.toDateString()}
            td
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table header elements need to be in `thead` to be recognised as a table head. Then the rest goes into the `tbody`.

See also https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/397 :

> ```
>   ...
>   table.table.tablesorter.table-bordered
>     thead
>       tr
>         th Name
>         th Label
>         th Created
>         th Expires
>         th Type
>         th Status
>         th.last
>     tbody
>       each tape in tapes
>   ...
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much @Lister now its working perfect thank you once again